# Dynamically assigning objects 2d array lua

Tags: lua

Below is the code i am trying to write. I am trying to dynamically assign objects to 2d array in lua. It is returning a error saying trying index a global nil value at line grid[i][j]=diceclass.new( ((i+2)/10),((j+2)/10)) ? Is there a way to fix this or what i am trying to do possible, dynamically assigning a object to each element of the array?

```
local diceClass = require( "dice" )
grid={}
for i =1,5 do
grid[i]=  {}
    for j =1,5 do

        grid[i][j]=diceclass.new( ((i+2)/10),((j+2)/10))
    end
end




--dice class
local dice = {}
local dice_mt = { __index = dice } 


function dice.new( posx, posy) 
a=math.random(1,6)
local newdice = display.newText(a, display.contentWidth*posx,
                                display.contentHeight*posy, nil, 60)

return setmetatable( newdice, dice_mt )
end



return dice
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: The problem i want to create a for loop which will create a 2d array of objects. At the line : grid[i][j]=diceclass.new( ((i+2)/10),((j+2)/10) i get a error saying trying to index global < a nil value> which is because i have not declared the objects beforehand. Is there a way to fix this error plus or to dynamically assign objects when creating a 2d array in lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diceClass` is not the same variable as  `diceclass`.

Comment: @David, a typo, not a syntax error. But the error message should have told you that: `attempt to index global 'diceclass' (a nil value)`.